# Xcode Deleted outlets still give errors

Tags: ios, xcode

I deleted one of my `ViewControllers` and its classes. There were a few outlets in them, and now errors for them won't go away.
Here's the error:

> The quoteTimestamp outlet from the UIViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Anybody have a possible solution/fix? Xcode bug?

Comment: You deleted the files, or the items in storyboard, or both? If the storyboard items are still existing, you have to go to the Connections Inspector and delete the outlets.

Comment: @Tim both were deleted

Comment: Hmm, OK, in storyboard did you also delete the whole viewController, or just the views in it like the UILabel?

Comment: I re-built the project and the errors went away, just another xcode issue :/ Thanks for the help though! @Tim

Comment: No problem. Clean build is always a good idea when you've got strange old errors.

Answer (score 0):

try (CMD+SHIFT+K) to clean project for the next time.